# How can I make PyCharm recognize Dockerfiles that are not called exactly Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, pycharm, dockerfile

In my project, there are several Dockerfiles. As they are in the same folder they can't all be named Dockerfile. PyCharm only styles the one named Dockerfile as Dockerfile. Dockerfile_1, for example, gets no styling and no inspections.

Comment: It seems impossible

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By following the directions [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-registering-file-types.html), do the following:

1. Navigate to `File` --> `Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac?)
2. Click on `Editor`
3. Click on `File Types`
4. Scroll until you find `Dockerfile` in the `Recognized File Types` list.
5. In the `Registered Patterns` area, click the plus symbol on the upper right.
6. Enter a pattern like `Dockerfile*`

Comment: It works! Can't believe it took so long to find a way. Thanky a lot :-)

Comment: There is no "Dockerfile" in the list for me, and I can't find anything online for where I can download new pre-configured file types to PyCharm.

Comment: I believe that you must have PyCharm Pro to get Docker integration. The community edition does not include it. Here's a [link to the editions comparison matrix](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).

Comment: I have PyCharm community, and installing "Docker' pycharm plugin worked perfectly without needed to fix File Types. This is what you need